# How to Color the Rails Console IRB prompt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Do not say the awesome_print gem because that only colors output, not the prompt.  I'm looking to customize the color of `irb(main):003:0>` because error messages are hard to distinguish from the prompt when they are the same color.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNbWV.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fancy_irb` is what you're looking for: https://github.com/janlelis/fancy_irb